# direcionar pagina com onclick dentro de um form

Tags: javascript, html, front-end, back-end, navegação

Basicamente o que eu preciso é por um botão ''voltar'' dentro do meu form. Tem que ser dentro por questões esteticas, o botão voltar ficaria inline com o botão enviar.

Fiz um codigo resumido:

```
    <form action="php/***.php" method="post">
        <p>DIGITE SEU NOME:
        <input type="text"  placeholder="nome" name="nome" id="nome"><p>

        <input type="submit">
        <a onClick="window.location='home.php';">
            <button style="margin-left: 10%" class="bt2" >Voltar</button>
        </a>
    </form>
```

Porém quando eu clico no botão ''voltar'' ele direciona para a pagina da action no form, e não para a pagina home do onclick.

Eu consegui fazer isso funcionar em uma pagina, porem se eu copio exatamente o mesmo codigo, não funciona em outras. Muito estranho.

Comment: Ao invés de usar `onClick`, não seria melhor usar `href`? `<a href="home.php">Voltar</a>`

Comment: usando href aí que o codigo não vai deixar mesmo, pois o action do form se sobrepoe. Como havia dito, em uma pagina consegui fazer o js se sobrepor ao html. Mas quando reproduzi o codigo ja nao funcionou mais =/

Comment: Não da para tirar o "a" e colocar o onClick direto no button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito estranho usar um botão dentro de um `<a>`, porque um botão por si só já tem a possibilidade de fazer um redirecionamento. Eu recomendaria em vez da fazer isso, colocar no `button` um `onclick="location.href='home.php'"` e retirar esse `<a>`, que seria o mais adequado.

Mas o problema mesmo é que falta um `type="button"` no botão, porque o `button` é por padrão um botão de `submit`, logo, sem o `type="button"`, ele irá chamar a URL do `action` do formulário.

Faça o seguinte: remova esse `<a>` e deixe o botão assim, com `type` e `onclick`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='home.php'" style="margin-left: 10%" class="bt2" >Voltar</button>
```